# Is it possible to disable foreign keys globally in Azure MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, azure

We use Azure MySQL database (MySQL version: 5.7). We have a process that needs to disable all the foreign keys in the database globally (and not only for a session).
When we try to use the command: `SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0`, this is the error:
"Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation"

We understand that we cannot give super privilege permissions to users and we also tried to change the server parameters but it seems there is no parameter for this issue.
Is it possible to disable foreign keys globally in Azure MySQL database?

Thank you!